# Get outter parent UL using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a specific li element within the closest/parent ul, however, I can't seem to get it working.  It only works if the div is within the li element.

```
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <a id="a_test" href="#" onclick="Javascript:get_li(this);">Test</a>
</div>

function get_li(oElement) {

  console.log("ul", $(oElement).parent("ul").find("li")[0]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#a_test').click(function() {

  var text = $(this).parent().prev('ul').find('li:nth-child(1)').text()
  alert(text)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <a id="a_test" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

You need to get to parent of anchor by using `.parent()` then get the ul using `.prev()` then find the li element using `.find()`

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because the `div` is not under the `ul` so the `div` is not a child of `ul` but **both your `ul` and `div` are siblings**. That means both these elements have same parent. So first find the parent of the `div` and now find the `ul` within this parent. Below is the sample

`$(oElement).closest('div').parent().find("ul li")[0]`

Comment: this work if there are other `UL` within the parent of div you need to specify the ul it that case